# Concatenate values in one column depending on other column s value

Tags: sql, concatenation

I need to concatenate col2 values depending on col1 value. Table looks like below:

```
Col1    Col2
----------------
1       10520.72
1       10520.71
2       10520.81
2       10520.82
3       10520.91
3       10520.92
```

I need query which displays like below:

```
Col1   Col2
-------------------------
1       10520.71-10520.72
2       10520.81-10520.82
3       10520.91-10520.92
```

I work with Toad, so `wm_concat`, `group_concat`, `array_to_string` won't work for me.

Please let me know how to do it.

Reena

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: i have written query like below: select t1.col2 || '-'|| t2.col2 , t1.col1 from t1,t2 where t1.col1=t2.col1 and t1.col2<>t2.col2;                                                                                        This will give 6 records instead of 3.

Comment: Post your query in your question

Comment: which version of sql does toad use

Comment: jeremy,                                                                                                      no idea. how to check that

Comment: I wrote something that works but it will round up your decimals, is that a problem?

Comment: yes, should not round up decimals.

Comment: @user3563011 if your table is defined as float and not decimal for the col2 field then my solution shouldn't round your value

Comment: scratch that, also works for decimals, just checked it out, only tricky part is you need to have defined decimal spaces in your table or it will round up to real numbers

Answer (score 0):

I remember seeing something similar before, had to edit it slightly to work with your float numbers though, here it is: [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/629b0/2) now also tested for decimal numbers: [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/54bcb/2)

```
Select m.col1, 
concat = STUFF((
          SELECT '-' + LTRIM(Str(md.col2, 25, 2))
          FROM mytable md
          WHERE m.col1 = md.col1
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM mytable m
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you

```
SELECT Col1, CAST(MIN(Col2) AS VARCHAR)+'-'+CAST(MAX(Col2) AS VARCHAR) AS Col2
FROM T_Table
GROUP BY Col1
```

Comment: this will only get the highest and lowest value though, not concat all values for that key

Comment: yakov, not working for me, saying left parantheses missing

Answer (score 0):

Here is your query...

SELECT DISTINCT
        COL1 ,
        CAST(CASE WHEN T1COL > T2COL THEN T1COL
                  ELSE T2COL
             END AS VARCHAR(50)) + '-'
        + CAST(CASE WHEN T2COL > T1COL THEN T1COL
                    ELSE T2COL
               END AS VARCHAR(40))
FROM    ( SELECT    T1.COL1 ,
                    T1.COL2 T1COL ,
                    T2.COL2 T2COL
          FROM      Table1 T1
                    INNER JOIN Table1 T2 ON T1.COl1 = T2.COl1
                                            AND T1.Col2 <> T2.Col2
        ) TblX;